# Run IIS Express without installing IIS

Tags: c#, batch-file, iis, iis-express

Can I run IIS Express without installing IIS? Is it possible?

Can I enable IIS by any batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the first question

> Can I run IIS Express without installing IIS?

Yes, but not (officially) without installing IIS Express itself. From [MS IIS Express FAQ](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-faq):

> **Q: Can IIS Express be redistributed or embedded in other applications?**
>
> A: The IIS 7.5 Express license allows the MSI to be redistributed. You
>   can include the MSI in your product or chain your installer to it. You
>   can't distribute IIS Express in any other manner at the moment.
>
> **Q: Is IIS Express xcopy-deployable?**
>
> A: The core IIS Express runtime is xcopy-deployable. However, as of
>   this time, xcopy deployment is not an officially supported feature.

The second question

> Can I enable IIS by any batch file?

Also, from the same source

> **Q: Does IIS Express support the command line?**
>
> A: Yes, IIS Express can be launched using the command line and
>   supports various runtime options. For information about how to use the
>   command line, see [Use the Command Line to Run a WebMatrix Site or
>   Application](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=195514).